# Compiling Android Studio Vulkan Samples

Tags: android, linux, vulkan

I'm trying to compile the Android Vulkan API Samples in AS3.4 on Manjaro.

I've downloaded and imported the project via the AS project splash screen.

When building I get this error:

ERROR: The project name 'API-Samples/android/' must not contain any of the following characters: [/, \, :, <, >, ", ?, *, |]. Set the 'rootProject.name' or adjust the 'include' statement

I'm new to Gradle so I don't know where it wants me to set the rootProject.name?

Answer (score 0):

The error only occurs after updating the Android Gradle Plugin:

"To take advantage of the latest features, improvements, and security fixes, we strongly recommend that you update the Android Gradle plugin to version 3.4.0 and Gradle to version 5.1.1. Release notes Android plugin 3.2.0 and higher now support building the Android App Bundle—a new upload format that defers APK generation and signing to compatible app stores, such as Google Play. With app bundles, you no longer have to build, sign, and manage multiple APKs, and users get smaller, more optimized downloads. Learn more"

If I cancel this update the samples build fine.